# Is the 'to' a typo or right usage?

Tags: prepositions

This is from an [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/12/opinion/what-makes-a-country-great-meet-haitis-people.html?&moduleDetail=section-news-1&action=click&contentCollection=Opinion&region=Footer&module=MoreInSection&version=WhatsNext&contentID=WhatsNext&pgtype=article) in the New York Times.

> When I was in high school, we had a program called Alphabetization.
>   High school seniors would volunteer to teach how to read and write to
>   illiterate elders from the community. I participated in it during my
>   senior year and taught many elders **to** joys of reading and math.
>   Some of them were octogenarians, yet still had the desire to learn.

Is the '**to**' a typo or right usage? I thought you can say '*I taught many elders joys of reading and math*' or '*I taught joys of reading and math to many elders.*'

Comment: Could you explain the grammar if it was correct?

Comment: @user3169: I looked up the dictionary for 'teach' but didn't see this kind of usage that's why I thought it is a typo. But I have limited knowledge of English grammar so I thought there might be something I was missing.

Comment: We TEACH something TO someone.  Or we TEACH someone TO DO something.  We can INTRODUCE someone TO something. *We introduced many illiterate elders to the joys of reading.*

Comment: But despite that slip, I would have to agree with the writer when he says. *...English is my third language, yet I speak it better than the president of the United States ...*

Comment: OK. In this case it is clear that *joy* is countable, since you listed two of them. So an article at least is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say

> I taught my elders the joys of reading.

or

> I taught my elders to read.

But you can't say you taught them "to joys" because "joys" is not a verb or a destination.